# Merging Partitions

Tags: 13.10, gparted

In an attempt to re-arrange/clean up the partitions on my dual boot laptop using gparted I seem to have run into a wall.  Here is my current partition layout:

/dev/sda1 - 25G fat32 Windows Recovery partition 
/dev/sda2 - 200G ntfs Windows 8 OS partition 
/dev/sda4 - 100G ntfs empty partition 
/dev/sda3 - 380G extended partition 
--/dev/sda5 - 190G ntfs empty partition 
--/dev/sda7 - 180G ext4 Ubuntu partition 
--/dev/sda6 - 8G linux-swap

I want to merge sda4 and sda5 into one large partition that can be accessed from both OS's.  I've been trying off the Ubuntu LiveCD GParted.  When I try and delete or do anything with sda5 I get a 'Please unmount any logical partitions higher then 5' error.

Comment: You should post the output of `sudo sfdisk -l -u S /dev/sda`. The order of partitions in the partition table and on disk do not necessarily match.

Answer (score 4):

For general information, it is easier to resize partitions when booting a live usb as you have unmount the partions before you resize them.

Once you boot a live CD/USB, the swap partition (with ubuntu) will mount automatically. Unmount it from within gparted or from the command line:

```
sudo swapoff -a
```

You then have to do your resizing in steps. Probably easy to:

delete sda4 -> apply changes

make sda3 bigger -> apply changes

make sda5 larger -> apply changes

Comment: +1, the OP *was* using a liveCD according to the question. I *think*, as you suggested, that the issue was the swap being mounted, I was going to post the same answer when you posted yours....

Comment: Ah missed that, thank you. Still booting a live usb is good advice.